# Text not being contained

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I made a very basic layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/kK7Rk/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="logocontainer">
    </div>
    <div id="navigationcontainer">
    </div>
    <div id="textcontainer">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebarcontainer">
        TEXTTEXTEXTTEXTTEXTEXTTEXTTEXTEXTTEXTTEXTEXTTEXTTEXTEXT.
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#container {
margin:0px auto;
width:600px;
height:1000px;
background:red;
}
#logocontainer {
float:left;
width:50%;
height:15%;
background:green;
}
#navigationcontainer {
float:right;
width:50%;
height:15%;
background:orange;
}
#textcontainer {
margin:10px;
float:left;
width:70%;
height:83.2%;
background:purple;
}
#sidebarcontainer {
margin:10px;
float:right;
width:23.33%;
background:yellow;
}​
```

The text inside  is flowing outside its boundaries even though I set a margin for the div.

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Thanks,

SenileSage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers don't know how to break words that are so long, you have to give it a bit of help.

Add `word-break:break-all;` to the `#sidebarcontainer`. Here is some more info on it on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

Comment: Consider adding `overflow:hidden;` for browsers that do not support that CSS3 property, yet.

Comment: Yes sorry. @jimp is correct. As Firefox and Opera are yet to support this fully, you will need to add `overflow:hidden;` just incase. Not the best case scenario, but better than it looking really odd. Keep in mind though that this 'error' case you're talking about is rare though.

Comment: I know about adding overflow:hidden, but it hides the rest of the text instead of making a new line :(.

Comment: Yeah, it is unfortunate but adding both is likely a good idea if you're thinking this will happen more than rarely.

Comment: @DCoder here is probably not the place for that.

Comment: @DCodern, yeah that is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @DCoder not meaning to have a go at your sorry. Just keep opinions out of answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your text has no whitespace so it cannot wrap. If you add `overflow:hidden;` to `#sidebarcontainer` it will hide the overflow and preserve your layout.

Comment: That doesn't exactly solve my problem because the rest of the text does not show up in a separate line.